# how to send traffic from mitmproxy to another proxy server

Tags: proxy, fiddler, mitmproxy

I have a need to redirect mitmproxy to another proxy server. Let say an example.

Browser -> mitmproxy -> fiddler

Browser proxy was  set to 8089
mitmproxy is running on 8089
fiddler listening on 8090
now how can i do proxy forward mitmproxy using -F

i tried mitmproxy -p 8089 -F localhost:8090, but the output was unrecognised argument -F

Any help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify an upstream proxy using `-U` (which was previously called `-F`).

Comment: I try this (-U) to redirect to another proxy, including a Proxy-Authorization header, but I only get error: ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED , I try to access to HTTPS like a youtube url

Comment: For everyone stopping by, I already answered the comment here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mitmproxy/32tGPvcLkA0

Answer (score 3):

`-U` is deprecated now. You shall use `--mode upstream:SPEC`

> `mitmproxy --mode  upstream:http://<target-proxy-ip>:<target-proxy-port> --upstream-auth  <target-proxy-user-name>:<target-proxy-password> -p 3128 --set  block_global=false`
>
> **Reference:** https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-modes/#upstream-proxy

**Example (allows outside connection):**

**Server-1**  (ip: x.x.x.x)

```
mitmproxy --proxyauth "user1:pass1" -p 3128 --set block_global=false
```

**Server-2**  (ip: y.y.y.y)

```
mitmproxy --mode upstream:http://x.x.x.x:3128 --upstream-auth user1:pass1 -p 3128 --set block_global=false
```

**Client**
Proxy: `y.y.y.y:3128`